# Ссылка на библиотеку WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Не могу адекватно добавить ссылку на созданную внутри проекта WinForm библиотеку пользовательских элементов WPF, ссылка идентифицируется с восклицательным знаком, без каких-либо явных ошибок и в `elementHost` пусто.
PS.
Как-то раз она у меня добавилась и прекрасно работала (библиотеку сделал сам).

> Дополнительно

**Переменная 'userControl11' либо не объявлена, либо ей не было присвоено значение.** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сама dll**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Пример кода

```
<UserControl x:Class="ASAMWPFElements.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ASAMWPFElements"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="47*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="253*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,123,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="78,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" Margin="10,23,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: PresentationCore, PresentationFramework и WindowsBase добавили?

Comment: да все эти библеотеки уже подключены

Comment: Тогда непонятно. Может, приложите код, поясняющий проблему?

Comment: он у меня ещё выдает ошибку на UserControl11 (с двумя 1) после сборки хотя до нее работает, вот похожий способ добавления http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/integrating-wpf-in-winforms-in-vs-2010/ только у меня библиотека пользовательских элементов WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в разных версиях .net программы и библиотеки

Answer (score 0):

Внутри проекта? Если мне память не изменяет, нужно на проекте правой кнопкой щелкнуть. Выбрать добавить референсы. И там будет несколько закладок.
- выбор из файла референсов (нажимают обычно этот пункт)
- с сайта
- из своего же проекта (нужен этот пункт)

Comment: Я похожим образом добавляю http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/integrating-wpf-in-winforms-in-vs-2010/ но после сборки основного проекта ссылка идентифицируется восклицательным знаком и elementHost становиться пустым ещё выдает ошибку на UserControl11

Comment: А та либо скомпилированна вообще? Может порядок компиляции нарушен? Например, проект не компилируется, так как нет либы. А либа компилируется вторая. Такое может быть?